# Why are we use twice bindVertexArray(vao)?

Tags: webgl

I am new person for WebGL and I am trying to learn WebGL2. But I don't really understand how to work WebGL. Especially, VAOs and VBOs. I looked for diagrams of how memory works, but I couldn't find it. I have given the following example and I will try to explain how the example works.

```js
function main(){
    // initialize GL
    // create vertex shader and fragment shader
    // create program

    var positionAttributeLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");

    var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);

    // define positions with array

    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(positions), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    var vao = gl.createVertexArray();

    gl.bindVertexArray(vao);

    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttributeLocation);

    // ....
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(
        positionAttributeLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset
    );

    gl.viewport(0, 0, 400, 300);

    // clear canvas
    // use program

    gl.bindVertexArray(vao);        // why we use that here ?

    var primitiveType = gl.TRIANGLES;
    var offset = 0;
    var count = 3;
    gl.drawArrays(primitiveType, offset, count);
}
```

1. Firstly, I got attribute in vertex shader program, we'll use for VAO. I able to think it's slot 0.
2. Then I created buffer for positions (array).
3. Activated buffer with `bindBuffer()` function.
4. Then positions added in buffer.
5. Created VAO and activated with `bindVertexArray()`.
6. Enabled slot 0 and I will add the data (positions) in slot 0. It is as parameter for `vertexAttribFunction()`.

That's the situation I can understand. Then the situation gets confused. Why are we call again bindVertexArray(vao)? Are there also detailed schemes of how VAOs and VBOs work within the WebGL?

Comment: OpenGL as WebGL is a state engine. `gl.bindVertexArray(vao)` binds the vertex array object and breaks the existing vertex array object binding. It is useless to bind the same VAO again. But note, if you've different vertex array objects, then you've to bind the proper VAO before the draw call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not normal to draw a single object in WebGL. If you have more than 1 object and you're using vertex array objects (VAOs) then

at init time

```
for each object
  create a vertex array object VAO and bind it
  create all the buffers for this object
  setup all the attributes for this object
```

at draw time

```
for each object
  bind the VAO for this object
  set uniforms for this object (and optionally bind textures for this object)
  draw
```

So yes, if you're only drawing a single thing then binding the VAO twice might seem strange but the pattern of binding the VAO once at init time and again at draw time is the normal thing to do because the normal thing to do is to draw multiple objects.

Note this is no different than any other stateful API. For example the canvas 2d API. You could write this

```
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';

function renderLoop(time) {
   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
   ctx.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);  // assume X and Y are animated
   ...
}
```

But it's again it's not normal to only draw one thing so most people, even if they only start with 1 thing would do this

```
function renderLoop(time) {
   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
   ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
   ctx.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);  // assume X and Y are animated
   ...
}
```

Even though it's redundant to set the `fillStyle` every frame. They do it because they expect to draw more things later so it becomes a pattern to *set the state related to the thing you want to draw right before you draw it*.

```
function renderLoop(time) {
   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
   ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
   ctx.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);  // assume X and Y are animated
   ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
   ctx.fillRect(x2, y2, 20, 20);  // assume x2 and y2 are animated
   ...
}
```

As for VAO state see [this](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-attributes.html) and texture state see [this](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-texture-units.html)

Comment: When I read above expert explanation, I wonder why I find myself binding both vao - using gl.bindVertexArray(vao)  and its associated positionBuffer - using gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,buf) prior to the drawArray() call. I need two binds in my render procedure, not one bind. When I don't bind the associated positionBuffer as well, the old values (of the previous vao) are used by vertex shader input of the second object.

Comment: You probably have a bug in your code. Here's an example: https://jsgist.org/?src=1f5f0ddf6ed9acdd4c916662a678847a

Comment: Aha checked it against your example.. I don't use twgl (I am in TypeScript) but i found the issue. I executed the part with enableVertexAttribArray() and vertexAttribPointer() in the render procedure as well. When I move that code into my initialization, I can remove gl.bindBuffer() from my render().. @gman thanks for the assist !

Comment: The example only used twgl to compile the shaders (since why bother cluttering the example with 20 lines of boilerplate)

Comment: I love that toolkit.. but I don't know how to get it to work with TypeScript yet. Someone did a .TS version [this one](https://github.com/quanterion/twgl-typescript) but that looks like WebGL and I want to use WebGL2. There's a [discussion](https://github.com/greggman/twgl.js/issues/50) on your github about it and a pull request of 2019 [this one](https://github.com/greggman/twgl.js/pull/102) but I'm sure what flavour I can use atm.. so I rolled my own shader compilation function. I'd love to be able to use the twgl uniforms definition/update system in TypeScript.

Comment: I'm not a typescript expert but it seems to work: https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-rgb-jc85ef

Comment: Pixel texture cube.. ran on the js version with "allowJs": true in the compiler config. Great example to start out with ! thanks again..