# Persistent undefined error in typescript import export

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

There's already a LOT of questions about typescript in multiple files.. for instance, this one,

[Typescript import/export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72692423/typescript-import-export)

Interesting question and answer, I simplified and tested it, see below.. but whatever I try, I still get

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'A')**

.. as does *any other example* of import/export in TypeScript I found online. Whatever I do, whatever object I try export (class, function, const) with or without using a module: I get the same error.

Maybe there is something wrong in my NPM/TSC/React configuration ? Should I change e.g. tsconfig.js when i want to use more than one typescript file in a project ? I'm lost, what do I miss ?

**tsconfig.json**

```
{ // TypeScript configuration file: provides options to the TypeScript 
  // compiler (tsc) and makes VSCode recognize this folder as a TS project,
  // enabling the VSCode build tasks "tsc: build" and "tsc: watch".
  "compilerOptions": {
   "target": "es5",            // Compatible with older browsers
   "module": "umd",            // Compatible with both Node.js and browser
   "moduleResolution": "node", // Tell tsc to look in node_modules for modules
   "sourceMap": true,          // Creates *.js.map files
   "jsx": "react",             // Causes inline XML (JSX code) to be expanded
   "strict": true,             // Strict types, eg. prohibits `var x=0; x=null`
   "alwaysStrict": true        // Enable JavaScript's "use strict" mode
  },
 "include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
 "exclude": ["node_modules"]
```

}

**first.tsx**

```
const A ={
  val: 'A'
}    
export { A }
```

**app.tsx**

```
import { A } from "./first";

// ... other code

function reportPerson()
{
  console.log(A);
}
```

.. Both files translate to .js with TSC, but A is reported by the Google Chrome console as undefined,

[image]

Both tsx files are in the same directory, TSC converts them both to JS without any issue.

What's going on ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for the advice (I didn't solve the above minimal example either..)

In order to properly link my stuff together, I've now put **Parcel 2** to work,

https://www.npmjs.com/package/parcel

```
npm i parcel
```

This is basically a bundler, that allows separate ts files to be concatenated after they are compiled to Javascript and it will put everything in a \dist directory,

```
parcel build src/index.html
```

Based on a small react example, I put my first "modulized" little app in TypeScript to work.  Then, with the help of [expert advise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58379626/why-are-we-use-twice-bindvertexarrayvao), I proceeded with twgl.js, which is a great toolkit for Webgl2.

```
npm install twgl.js
```

This javascript library even has *sub-modules*.. and everything links fine now, I can access (all of?) twgl with

```
import * as twgl from "./twgl-full.js";
```